# WF Rules - Chaining for Indexers

Tags: workflow-foundation, chaining, rule, indexer

Entity-Attribute pattern is used in our application structure (i.e.,) Properties are represented in key-value pairs and accessed via indexers.

Planning to use workflow rule engine for configuring rules in this structure. But can't find chaining mechanism application samples any where. Need to know how to apply chaining in rules if the indexer properties are used?

Regards,

Mani.M

Comment: What do you mean by chaining?

Comment: Chaining establishes the execution flow of rules based on property update. eg. In a Consumer Entity, if two rules are configured. One to calculate salary and other for bonus. Salary calculation should precede before bonus. It will be established by chaining functionality of wrokflow rule engine.

Comment: Just want to apply the same for indexers. Need to know how to apply it.

Comment: So effectively you're just trying to specify the order in which the rules will execute?

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is set the `Priority` of the rule before adding it to the `RuleSet` so that way WF can order the rule properly. You will want to create your own `RuleSet` to make this easier and here is an example below of something that you might want to do.

```
public class MyRuleSet
{
    // this is the WF rule set
    private RuleSet ruleSet = new RuleSet();

    private const int maxRuleSetSize = 1000;

    public void AddRule(Rule rule)
    {
        rule.Priority = maxRuleSetSize - (this.ruleSet.Rules.Count + 1);
        this.ruleSet.Rules.Add(rule);
    }
}
```

Then when you're ready to execute the rules you'll need to build the `RuleSet` with your new `RuleSet` so that they are executed in the order they are added.

```
var ruleSet = new MyRuleSet();
ruleSet.AddRule(new Rule1());
ruleSet.AddRule(new Rule2());
...
```

And then you'll need to execute that `RuleSet`.

Comment: Sorry... this is manual setting of rules priority.. normally, for a particular entity, rules can be added at any time and user doesn't know the existing rules. And setting priority on adding a rule does not work if rules are added at different times... If this is the solution, there is no need for built in chaining in rule engines. It is one of th characteristics of rule engine... correct answer pls...

Comment: @user1606558 - unfortunately the way the WF rule engine works is to execute a `RuleSet` linearly so maybe the answer is that it won't work for you.